# Is it worth introducing "incorrect" results to avoid crashing a program?

Tags: error-handling

In my organisation, I see a lot of places where code has been put inside monitor blocks (RPG's version of try..except) to prevent raising exceptions on arithmetic errors. For instance:

```
Monitor;                    
  Pxxhour = Bctime/60;      
  PxxMin  = %Rem(Bctime:60);
On-Error;                   
  Pxxhour = 0;              
  PxxMin  = 0;
```

`Pxxhour` and `Pxxmin` are screen fields that will be displayed to users. So if there is an error in the operations, these get a value of 0. Though this prevents the program from crashing, how does it help? Users keep seeing the wrong values on the screen. Similarly, I see code which assigns the highest possible value for a given variable rather than allowing an overflow exception. Though this will prevent the program from blowing up, how does it help in the long run? Wouldn't calculations have wrong values and result in wrong business data?

---

*The answers given below by @jmarkmurphy and @Charles successfully address the question from an RPG and IBM midrange perspective, which is what I was after.*

Comment: You seem to understand just fine. Things are (apparently) just as you describe. So **exactly** what is your problem? It seems like you actually want to know good ways to make progress against what you see. BTW, is `Bctime` null-capable?

Comment: Please read the question again. My question is not on how the monitor block works. Its on why they might have been written this way. If anyone sees any rationale on suppressing errors in this way, please explain.

Comment: `...how does it help?` It helps by `...prevent(ing) the program from crashing`. And `...how does it help in the long run, wouldnt calculations be have wrong values and result in wrong Business data?` (1) Prevents crashes, (2) wrong results and (3) wrong data -- all true. `(A)ny thoughts please?` You're correct in everything. So what are you actually looking for? I read the question the first time and again, and nothing has changed. What are you actually asking if it's not simple validation of your understanding? There are at least two distinct directions to head into.

Comment: So this question has basically nothing to do with monitor blocks at all, and isn't specific to RPG or IBM midrange. The same question would apply to code that only involves `if..then..else` but with the same fundamental logic. The subject line is thus misleading and the tags are superfluous.

Comment: Thanks John for the feedback. If you feel this post needs to be reported or deleted to avoid people getting mislead, please do it if you can. If possible, feel free to change the subject and tags so that this post becomes useful to the public. If you are able to make this question useful without deleting it, please advise people to go through Murphys and Charles' answers only. Because other answers are more misleading than the question.

Comment: This is opinion based question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What Should I Do When I Have Errors in my Calculations**

Programs that blow up on users are bad, even if it is the *user's fault*. It makes the user believe that the program is buggy, and then anything unexpected that happens becomes the program's fault; something to be fixed. Things can get really out of hand in this manner causing help desk calls for ordinary occurrences that just appear a little odd, even when the outcome is actually correct.

One option is to validate the user input to prevent calculation errors, but what do you do when you can't really prevent all of them. In our world, one of these situations is in invoicing. 5250 screens have limited real estate and you can't always make the fields big enough to hold all eventualities. So there are tradeoffs. Maybe you need to be able to sell thousands of some small items on a single invoice, but the largest total invoice you have ever had is $100K. So you size your fields like this:

```
dcl-s quantity        Packed(5:0);
dcl-s unitPrice       Packed(7:2);
dcl-s ammount         Packed(9:2);
```

All are odd because they take up the same space on disk as the next lower even precision. You don't sell fractional quantities, and the maximum value in each field is:

```
quantity = 99,999;
unitPrice = $99,999.99;
amount = $9,999,999.99;
```

Now you can see that these maximums should easily handle all valid invoices, but it also leaves plenty of potential for calculation errors. If the user keys in maximum numbers for quantity and unitPrice, the resulting number would require a Packed(12:2) field. That would cause an overflow. In an invoice when the unit price is stored in the invoice detail, we can add an edit when the quantity and unit price is entered that checks for an extended amount overflow, and send an appropriate error message. But what if unit prices are not stored in the invoice detail, but instead in a pricing table. Now there is not a good way, if a price is changed for example to ensure that none of the existing invoices will be affected adversely.

So what do you do about a decimal overflow, or any other calculation error, be it a data problem, or something else? And what happens if the error occurs Blowing up the program is not a good option. Another option, the one that seems to be taken in the question is to apply some default value that the users will quickly recognize is out of the ordinary. It will appear in reports, and on screens. When the users see those excessively large, or small numbers, then they can know to go back and check the data.

Comment: This is opinion based.

Comment: @danny117 the only opinion here is that allowing programs to blow up on users is a bad idea. You have a different opinion?

Answer (score 2):

There's two use cases for a `MONITOR` block...

1. Expected errors
2. Unexpected errors

For expected errors, replacing bad or invalid data with an accepted value is a valid solution in some cases.  The trick is knowing which cases.  The answer to that is something your business people would need to help decide.  Depends of what the program is doing and what data has the problem.

For instance, given some sort of internal sales report, you might have something like so:

```
dcl-c DIVIDE_BY_ZERO  const(00102);
dcl-c RESULT_TO_LARGE  const(00103);

monitor;
  averageSale = totalSalesAmount / numberSales;
on-error DIVIDE_BY_ZERO;
  averageSale = 0;
on-error RESULT_TO_LARGE;
  averageSale = *HIVAL;
endmon;
```

What's important about the above is that I'm expecting one of two possible errors and I've decided to handle them a certain way.  The business people don't care that technically averageSale is undefined when numberSales is *ZERO.  They'y just want a zero to appear on the report.  They also understand that there's only so much room on the page and that if the number is all nines, the actual value might be bigger.

And unexpected error, such as a decimal data error, would not be caught be this `MONITOR` block.

For an unexpected caught by a monitor block via a `ON-ERROR` with `*ALL` or no error code specified, I'd expect to see some sort of logging of the issue followed by either skipping the problem record or cleaning shutting down depending on what the program is doing in the first place.

It appears that your code is expecting certain error(s), but without explicitly defining which error(s) codes it's willing to handle.  **This is lazy and not a good practice.**

As far as your questions about rather or not the handling of those expected errors is valid...**only you and your users can decide that**

You might want to take a look at Chapter 7 - *Exception and error handling* of the IBM Redbook [Who Knew You Could Do That with RPG IV? Modern RPG for the Modern Programmer](https://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg245402.html?Open)

Comment: Thanks Charles..  all this makes sense now